# SVRevealViewController does wrong offset from the top layout guide

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have simple `SearchViewController` with menu button at the top left corner.

Using `SVRevealViewController` I automatically setup front view controller.

[image]

It works and looks like this:

[image]

but later on action from this controller I load this controller once again using something like this:

```
revealViewController().setFrontViewController(UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController(), animated: true)
```

and then it looks like following:

[image]

and this is wrong. Why it happens like that?

My **Search.storyboard** is a `PageViewController` with two types of pages. First of them is my `SearchViewController`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pushFrontViewController` instead of `setFrontViewController`.